# How to connect AWS RDS for SQL Server to ODBC data sources via Linked Server connections?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, odbc, amazon-rds, amazon-data-pipeline

**Setup**

- Currently we are using SQL Server installed on an EC2 instance as our central data warehouse. We pull in data from a long list of data sources.

  - This is done via SQL Agent Jobs that execute Stored Procedures querying the data sources.
- The SQL Server instance has Linked Server connections to several databases (Postgres, MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server) and also to Hive.

  - These data sources are either on-premise or also deployed in AWS.
  - The connections are enabled by ODBC drivers which we installed directly on EC2.

**Problem**

Now there is a new company rule that we *have* to use AWS RDS for SQL Server instead of EC2. The problem is that AWS RDS does not support installing our own ODBC drivers. So we can't connect to the data sources anymore.

**Question**

How could we go about connecting AWS RDS to data sources which previously we could talk to via Linked Server + ODBC drivers?

**Note**

Abandoning SQL Server altogether should only be a last resort. There are lots of SSIS packages and migrating them to a new technology would take a lot of time and effort, so should be avoided if possible.

Comment: Q: Did you ever find a solution?  The only viable workaround I'm aware of is to install SQLExpress on a Windows host, co-locate the ODBC DSN on the same Windows host, and create a linked server in SQLExpress.   Did you ever find a way to use ODBC directly with the AWS/RDS instance (without any extraneous SQLExpress instance)?

Comment: Personally I switched companies, so I don't know if they sticked to the plan of absolutely having to use RDS in a scenario in which it doesn't make sense IMHO.

But here are two approaches that could make this work, even if IMHO both of them have absurd downsides:
A) Use AWS DMS + AWS Glue Jobs to ingest data into your new AWS RDS instance -> Now you have to rewrite all SSIS packages for the sake of using RDS... 
B) Keep SSIS running on the existing EC2 instance but load the data into the new RDS instance -> Now you pay a lot more money and still run the instance you wanted to shut down